# pyqt5 automagically adds QSpinBox (?) inside a table cell

Tags: pyqt5

Sorry about the title but I am not even sure for the right name of this kind of "widget".

Whenever I add

```
if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
    return 42 # or any other numeric value
```

in `data(self, index:QModelIndex, role=None)` method of my model (subclass of `QAbstractTableModel`)   a cell gets edited, the cells gets two small triangles on right, one facing up, another facing down, on which I can click so that the (integer) value in the cell is incremented or decremented

This is very annoying since I didn't ask for this behavior, and I don't know from where it comes from. This prevents me from entering non-numeric values inside the cell, and I have no other choice than deleting it, and re-enter new formula / value

How can I prevent this behavior?

Picture:
[image: unwanted widget]

Comment: Return a string, rather than a numeric type.

Comment: you mean, I just cast to string all numerics I return, and when I need to calculate again, I cast them back to numerics?

Comment: That's one way to do it - or you could store the original numerical value in a custom role.

Comment: Then again, if the user can enter non-numerical values, what sort of calculation would you perform on them?

Comment: I let user enter his formulas, which get numerically evaluated, and return the result (à la Excel)

Comment: So in fact you should be using a custom item-delegate which provides a suitable editor for entering formulas, and then displays the result as a numerical value (or whatever).

Comment: thank you, I 'll take a look on that. For now I will just stick with the less effort solution